Is the composition of a $ C^\infty $ function with a saturation function still $ C^\infty $?
I am studying the composition of functions and their differentiability properties. Specifically, I have a $ C^\infty$ function $ f $ and a saturation function defined as:
$$
\text{sat}(u) = 
\begin{cases} 
a & \text{if } u < a \\ 
u & \text{if } a \leq u \leq b \\ 
b & \text{if } u > b 
\end{cases}
$$
I want to know whether the composition $ f(\text{sat}(u))$ is still $ C^\infty $. I understand that $ \text{sat}(u)$ is continuous but not differentiable at the limits $[a , b]$.
In fact, it is important that the function $f$ has the property of being derivable in $(a,b)$.(In my work I am looking to find the 2nd derivative of $f$  in the presence of saturation input.)
Can anyone provide insights on whether the composition retains the smoothness properties of $ f $?

The composition of $f$ with $sat(u)$ will be $C^{\infty}$ in $ (a,b) $ but not in $[a,b]$ exactly because the saturation function is not even $C^1$ in $[a,b]$. Remember that the first derivative of this composite function will be $(f(sat(u)))' = f'(sat(u))(sat(u))'$

Thank you for your quick answer.. It is clear that the other derivative of $f$ will be zero in the intervals of $u<a$ and $u>b$, therefor there are higher order derivatives of $f$ in all the intervals $[a,b]$.

Let think of an example: let $a=-2$ and $b = 2$, and let $f(x)$ been a smooth bump function defined for all real-values but non-zero only on the interval $(-1,\ 1)$, as example $$f(x) =\begin{cases} e^{\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}},\quad |x|<1;\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ now if I use $f(sat(x))$ as you defined it I don't see at first glance any issues... but I am not fully sure if this is what are you trying to achieve: maybe extend you question a bit on what you are trying to achieve (maybe some draws)
